# Zariski vs analytic cohomology of $\mathcal O_X^\times$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, analytic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X/\mathbf C$ be a smooth proper variety. Is it true that $H^1(X, \mathcal O_X^\times) = H^1(X^{an}, \mathcal O_{X^{an}}^\times)?$ GAGA doesn't apply, because $\mathcal O_X^\times$ is not coherent (let alone an $\mathcal O_X$-module)...

Comment: The LHS is the algebraic Picard group, the RHS is the analytic Picard group. Doesn't GAGA say these are the same?

Comment: Dear @Zhen: On a projective variety yes, because the categories of coherent sheaves on the two sites are equivalent. But for a proper variety, this part of GAGA doesn't hold, as far as I know...

Comment: The proper version (hah!) appears as Théorème 4.4 in [SGA 1, Exposé XII].

Comment: Dear @Zhen: Well that is a proper answer! If you'd like to post it, I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is well known that $H^1 (X, \mathscr{O}_X^\times)$ is (isomorphic to) the algebraic Picard group (= group of algebraic line bundles) and that $H^1 (X^\mathrm{an}, \mathscr{ O}_{X^\mathrm{an}}^\times)$ is (isomorphic to) the analytic Picard group (mutatis mutandis). So it suffices to show that there is an isomorphism between the two Picard groups.

We have the following result of Grothendieck, extending the result of Serre:

> **Theorem.** Let $X$ be a proper $\mathbb{C}$-scheme. Then the functor that sends a coherent sheaf $\mathscr{F}$ on $X$ to the coherent sheaf $\mathscr{F}^\mathrm{an}$ on $X^\mathrm{an}$ is an equivalence of categories.

This is Théorème 4.4 in [SGA 1, Exposé XII]. Since the functor $\mathscr{F} \mapsto \mathscr{F}^\mathrm{an}$ preserves $\otimes$, it follows that we have the required isomorphism of Picard groups.

Comment: Dear Zhen, how does Grothendieck's theorem  apply for  $\mathscr{O}_X^\times$, which  is never coherent ?

Comment: Sure. But as I said, it suffices to prove that the Picard groups are isomorphic, and line bundles are certainly coherent sheaves.

Comment: Dear Zhen, I agree:  I always compute  the Picard group as    $H^1 (X, \mathscr{O}_X^\times)$, so that I misunderstood your correct answer. Sorry and +1.

Comment: Ah. For me, the Picard group is first defined to be the group of line bundles and then shown to be isomorphic to that $H^1$. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Dear Zhen, your point of view is definitely the correct one: cohomology is a great way to compute the Picard group, but the definition should indeed be in terms of line bundles. And congratulations for knowing SGA so well!

Comment: Thank you for the kind comments! But all I did was chase references.